# Coordinate of All Blocks in a given Selection - Minecraft

Tags: minecraft

With reference to this [minecraft: How to get coordinates of blocks inside selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334033/minecraft-how-to-get-coordinates-of-blocks-inside-selection)

I was wondering if it was possible to generate a list of coordinates of all blocks present within a selection(a selection made by selecting pos1 and pos2 using world edit) of a certain type . thanks

Comment: maybe this is a question more suited for arcade.stackexchange since it is directly refering to a game.

Comment: Is this for a mod of some sort? Tag the question with bukkit, forge, java, etc. as needed. If it's for command blocks, go to the arcade stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

See `BlockPos#getAllInBox`. It provides multiple variants which includes a version with `BlockPos, BlockPos`. And then you can filter through the blocks within (`World#getBlockState`) and compare with a blockstate instance from `Blocks.SOMETHING.getDefaultState()`, or by comparing `Block` instance by calling `BlockState#getBlock()`.